# IntelliJ の maven プロジェクトで Main Class をマニフェストに記述する方法

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ でJavaアプリケーションを開発しているのですが、
mavenではない普通のプロジェクトはartifactsから生成したjarでmain classも指定でき、
実行コマンドでそのまま動作させることが出来るのですが

mavenプロジェクトの場合は同じよにしてもマニフェストにMainクラスが定義されていないとエラーになり実行できません。

jarを分解して.MFを見てみても確かにメインクラスの記述が抜けていました
どうすればIntelliJのMavenプロジェクトのartifactsで生成したjarのマニフェストにmain classを定義できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavenの場合、JAR Pluginを使えばMain Classを指定できます。

Apache Maven JAR Plugin
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/

---

以下は簡単な使用例です。

**ディレクトリ構成**

```
Maven
|   pom.xml
\---src
    \---main
        \---java
            \---com
                \---harry0000
                        Main.java
```

**src/main/java/com/harry0000/Main.java**

```
package com.harry0000;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, maven.");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.harry0000</groupId>
    <artifactId>Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.harry0000.Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addExtensions>false</addExtensions>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pluginの`<configuration>/<archive>/<manifest>/<mainClass>`にclassを指定します。
(例では`com.harry0000.Main`)

[Usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html)ページにある通り、`mvn package`を実行すれば`target`ディレクトリに実行可能なjarが生成されます。

```
D:\Maven> mvn package

(中略)

D:\Maven> java -jar .\target\Maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Hello, maven.
```

IntelliJからjarを生成する場合は下記の通りです。

1. `[View] - [Tool Windows] - [Maven Projects]`を選択
2. 対象Projectの`Lifecycle`にある`package`を右クリックし、`Run 'Maven[package]'`を実行

---

pluginの`<configuration>/<archive>`に設定する値の詳細は下記ページを参照してください。

Apache Maven Archiver
https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こんなに早く解決できるとは…私の寝なかった丸一日…
なんかのバグと思い色々試したんですよね…

本当にありがとうございます！
最後の最後のjarリリース時に大きな壁にあたって挫けそうでした